# Facebook like button stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I started having problems a couple of days ago with the Like button on my Facebook application page. It has been working for almost 6 months but stopped working yesterday. When I am logged into my own Facebook account I see the 'Like' count, but if I am logged out or logged in as anyone who hasn't already 'Liked' my app, it doesn't work. They see the button as if nobody has 'liked' it yet and when they click it, it seems to reset every time.

The URL I am trying to like is an APP URL. My code is pasted below.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id={myAppId}&amp;href={myAppURL}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=21" 
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
        style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" 
        allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

I've tried a few variants of this code, but I can't seem to get it to work. Even when I go to the page that generates 'Like' button code on Facebook and give it my URL, I see the same problem. When I click the button I get the text "Error" in red to the right of the button. I've seen an article on Mashable that this same problem happened about a year ago for some people...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `http://` part of the `src` attribute with `//`

So it should look like this:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id={myAppId}&amp;href={myAppURL}&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=21" 
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" 
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this change made no difference. Any other ideas. I've been searching the forums and seen a lot of people with the same problem in the past, but none of the solutions that have worked for other people seem to be working.

Comment: I suspected that the fact that I hadn't created an SSL Cert for my site may have been the problem because that was enforced on Oct. 1, but I added SSL support tonight and I am still seeing this problem. Is it possible that this is a Facebook bug that has just emerged again? The only warning I get from the DEBUG tool is one that I see with almost every app page. 
Extraneous Property-Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:site_url. I don't think this is the problem. Could someone at Facebook please look into it for me? My app URL is http://apps.facebook.com/speeksy